# Why won't my img show?

Tags: php, sql, css, html

Had this all working with html. Then I tried making it into html5 and I'm coding some of my first css code. The only thing I'm tackling right now is why isn't my image showing?? I'm using google chrome btw. The code passed in the url is this: "?fname=raichu&yesorno=true%2F" And there is no image tag in my generated html :/ I'm assuming that the if statement is equating to false??

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css"> 

 td{
    text-align: center;
    padding:15px;
    background-color:black;
    color:#00FF00;}

 th{
    background-color:black;
    color:yellow}

</style>

         <title>Search Results</title>

</head>

    <body style="color:#FFFFFF"> 

<?php

$dbhost = 'server';
$dbname = 'database1';
$dbuser = 'me';
$dbpass = 'password';

$link = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

mysqli_select_db($link,$dbname);

$naame = $_GET["fname"];


if( $_GET["yesorno"] == 'true' OR !$_GET["yesorno"])
            {$query = sprintf("SELECT image_url, Type 
                               FROM Pokemon c 
                               WHERE c.name='%s'", mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$naame));

    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link,$query));

    echo '<img height="450" width="330" src="'.$result['image_url'].'" alt="blue"/>';}

$res = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT Name,HP,Type,Pokedex_Number AS 'Pokedex  Number',Weakness,Resistance,Retreat AS 'Retreat Cost' 
                           FROM Pokemon 
                           WHERE Pokedex_Number!=0 AND name='$naame'");

if (!$res) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");}

    $fields_num = mysqli_num_fields($res);

echo "<h1>Stats</h1>";
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";

// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{$field = mysqli_fetch_field($res);
echo "<th>{$field->name}</th>";}

echo "</tr>\n";

// printing table rows
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($res))
{
echo "<tr>";

// $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
// of $row to $cell variable
foreach($row as $cell)
    echo "<td>$cell</td>";

echo "</tr>\n";
}   

echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($link);

    ?>

<br />
<form method="link" 
action = "http://engr.oregonstate.edu/~bainro/welcome.php" ><input 
type="submit" value="(>O.O)>RETURN<(O.O<)"></form>
<p></p>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you paste value of image_url ?

Comment: are you sure you are passing the right address

Comment: How do I post the generated html?

Comment: Right-click anywhere inside your web page, then click on View Source. Find the `<img ...>` tag and copy-paste that part in your question. Or you can copy-paste the whole generated html if it's not too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable you are retrieving from the url, is never evaluating to true because '%2F' is a forward slash. Check your code.

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
&yesorno=true%2F
```

therefore $_GET['yesorno'] will equate to 'true/' as %2f is a forward slash.

This doesn't match

```
if( $_GET["yesorno"] == 'true' OR !$_GET["yesorno"])
```

So you're correct - that line is failed so you won't get the image.

Solution: remove the %2F from the query.